# Insertar datos de un formulario con seleccion multiple a una base de datos

Tags: php, mysql

Hago esta consulta para resolver una duda que tengo en php (dado que en mi empresa me pidieron armar un sitio web interno para gestión de  en php, y tengo que usar un código base antiguo para armarlo. Primero, les presento los dos archivos .php relevantes, uno que tiene nombre equipos.php y el otro que tiene por nombre envio.php, donde el segundo gestiona el envío de datos.

Les presento el codigo relevante del primer php, y el codigo completo del segundo php

Aqui esta el codigo relevante del primer php:

```
    <?php include('header.php'); ?>
<?php include('session.php'); ?>
    <body>
        <?php include('navbar.php'); ?>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <?php include('newdevice_slidebar.php'); ?>

                <div class="span9" id="content">
                     <div class="row-fluid">
                     <a href="device_stocks.php" class="btn btn-info"  id="add" data-placement="right" title="Click para volver a stock de equipos" ><i class="icon-arrow-left icon-large"></i> Volver a stock de equipos</a>
                     <a href="movimientos.php" class="btn btn-info" id="move" data-placement="right" title="Click para asignar equipo a persona"><i class="icon-retweet"></i> Asignar Equipo a Usuario</a>

                      <script type="text/javascript">
                      $(document).ready(function(){
                      $('#add').tooltip('show');
                      $('#add').tooltip('hide');
                      });
                     </script> 

    <div class="block-content collapse in">
   <div class="span12">
    
<form id="send" method="post">  
<div class="empty">
    <div class="control-group">
         <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">Nombre del Lugar</label>
             <div class="controls">
                  <select name="stdev_id" class="chzn-select" required/>
                    <option></option>
                      <?php $result =  mysql_query("select * from stlocation")or die(mysql_error()); 
                      while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){ ?>

                   <option value="<?php echo $row['stdev_id']; ?>&nbspName&nbsp<?php echo $row['stdev_location_name']; ?>"><?php echo $row['stdev_location_name']; ?></option>
                    <?php } ?>
                   </select>
            </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
                                            <label class="control-label" for="input">Nro de Acta</label>
                                            <div class="controls">
                                            <input type="text" class="span8" name="nro_acta" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Ingresar acta" required>
                                            </div>
                                        </div> 
      <div class="control-group"> 
        <div class="controls">
        <button  class="btn btn-primary" id="snd" data-placement="right" title="Click to Assign"><i class="icon-share"> Asignar Oficina</i></button>
         <script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function(){
         $('#snd').tooltip('show');
         $('#snd').tooltip('hide');
         
         });
        </script>
                     
         <div class="pull-right">
               </div>
      </div>
 </div>
</div>


    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery("#send").submit(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();{                                                
            var formData = jQuery(this).serialize();
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "send.php",
            data: formData,
            success: function(html){
                        
                    
            $.jGrowl("Device Successfully Assign", { header: 'Device Assign' });
            var delay = 500;
            setTimeout(function(){ window.location = 'device_location.php'  }, delay);  
                        
            }
                                                
         });
            
       }
    }); }); </script>
```

Y aqui va el codigo relevante del segundo php:

```
<?php include('./lib/dbcon.php'); dbcon(); include('session.php'); $id = $_POST['selector']; $stdev_id = $_POST['stdev_id']; $nro_acta = $_POST['nro_acta']; $dev_Inv = $_POST['dev_Inv']; if ($id == '') {
header("location: device_location.php");
exit; } else {     // Captura el valor seleccionado del menú desplegable
list($stdev_id, $stdev_location_name) = explode("&nbspName&nbsp", $stdev_id);

$query = mysql_query("select * from location_details order by ld_id DESC") or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
$ld_id = $row['ld_id'];

$N = count($id);
for ($i = 0; $i < $N; $i++) {
    $oras = strtotime("now");
    $ora = date("Y-m-d", $oras);
    mysql_query("insert location_details (id,stdev_id,date_deployment) values('$id[$i]','$stdev_id','$ora')") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_query("insert into activity_log (date,username,action) values(NOW(),'$admin_username','Assign Device id $id[$i] to location id $stdev_id')") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_query("INSERT asignaciones (dev_Inv, nro_acta, fecha_movimiento) VALUES ('$dev_Inv', '$nro_acta', '$ora')") or die(mysql_error());
    

    // Actualizar la columna 'ubicacion' en stdevice
    mysql_query("UPDATE stdevice SET ubicacion = '$stdev_id', dev_status = 'DISPONIBLE' WHERE dev_Inv = '$id[$i]'") or die(mysql_error());
    // Actualizar asignaciones para insertar datos
    
}



header("location: device_location.php");
exit; } ?>
```

La idea es que el codigo inserte los valores en la tabla asignaciones, a partir de los valores obtenidos por el selector, pero no logro hacer que funcione. cualquier ayuda me es bienvenida. Creo que el codigo no funciona en la parte final, cuando inserta los datos en la tabla asignaciones (asi se llama en la base), ya que inserta todo lo demas en las correspondientes tablas sin problemas, mas no hace ese query

Comment: Sé más específico en cuál crees que es el problema o hasta dónde llegaste o algún detalle más. En base al código que pusiste se pueden deducir infinitas cosas, sé específico.

Comment: Creo que el codigo no funciona en la parte final, cuando inserta los datos en la tabla asignaciones (asi se llama en la base), ya que inserta todo lo demas en las correspondientes tablas sin problemas, mas no hace ese query. Mas especificamente, en este extracto de codigo `mysql_query("INSERT asignaciones (dev_Inv, nro_acta, fecha_movimiento) VALUES ('$dev_Inv', '$nro_acta', '$ora')") or die(mysql_error());`

Comment: Como no colocas en qué versión estás trabajando, ¿Sabes que las instrucciones `mysql_*` fueron declaradas obsoletas desde PHP 5.5 y eliminadas desde 7.0? En su defecto usar `mysqli_*` o mejor aún `PDO`. Debes actualizar el código.

Comment: Estoy trabajando en php anterior a 5.5, lamentablemente estoy usando un codigo de legado, por lo que no puedo actualizar

Comment: Que es lo que quieres hacer con **$ora**??? Por más que le busco, no entiendo el trabajo de esa variable?? Le has hecho un **echo** para ver cual es su contenido??

Comment: Creo que el problema es tan simple como que la sintaxis es `INSERT INTO [tabla]`, no sólo `INSERT [tabla]`